# Apply on Dataframe passes first row values to all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-docx, pandas-apply

When using apply in the below way, the values that get passed as "row" are exclusively those from the first row of the dataframe.

```
df.apply(make_word_file, axis=1)
```

Oddly, the file name created in the document.save() is correct. `newname` has the correct values in row['case_name']. However if I `print(row)` it prints the values from the first row.

```py
def make_word_file(row):
    for key, value in mapfields.items():
#         print(row)
        regex1 = re.compile(key)
        replace1 = str(row[value])
        docx_replace_regex(document, regex1 , replace1)

    newname = remove(row['case_name'], '\/:*?"<>|,.')
    print(newname)
    document.save(datadir + row["datename"] + "_" + row["court"] + "_" + newname + ".docx")
```

I expected `print(row)` to print the values from each row in the dataframe not just the 1st.

**EDIT for clarity:**

This script is a mail merge which makes .docx word files.
`mapfields` is a dict in the format of regex:column name. `document` is a docx-python object.

```
mapfields = {
"VARfname": "First Name",
"VARlname": "Last Name",
}
```

Comment: I tried the same thing using df.iterrows and same result:

```for row, index in df.iterrows():
    case_row = df.iloc[row]
    make_word_file(case_row)```

Comment: Unclear question. What is `mapfields`, `document`, what are these regexes for and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited for clarity. I am trying to generate docx file, i.e. a mail merge, from an existing .docx template. The way I do the mail merge is using a dict (`mapfields`) that maps the regex keys to replace in the template to the column names of `df` that I want to replace.

Comment: You show nothing of the dataframe. What shows `df.apply(print, axis=1)`?

Comment: I'm thinking my document template `document` gets overwritten and thus there are not regexs to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a loop/python-docx issue not a pandas one.

The `document` object was being overwritten, leaving nothing for the regex to find after the first one. Loading the document template in the function fixed the issue.

```
def make_word_file(case_row):
    document_template = Document(directory + fname)
    document = document_template
    for key, value in mapfields.items():
        regex1 = re.compile(key)
        replace1 = str(case_row[value])
        docx_replace_regex(document, regex1 , replace1)

    document.save(location + ".docx")
```